# Cast list to Any gives empty Map in Kotlin

Tags: karate

What is the correct syntax (instead of square brackets) to reliably cast a list to Any?

From the following code I expect (in Kotlin):
`Event("foo", mapOf(key1: listOf("item1","item2"), key2: "value2")`

but instead it's:
`Event("foo", mapOf(key1: emptyMap(), key2: "value2")`

---

Karate code

```
* def Event= Java.type('<...>.Event')
* def event = new Event('foo', { key1: ['item1','item2'], key2: 'value2' } )
```

Kotlin code

```
data class Event(
    val type: String, 
    var context: Map<String, Any>
)
```

Comment: I honestly have no idea